# Need to run ipconfig /renew every time

Tags: windows, networking, wifi-configuration, ip-address

When I connect to my phone's hotspot. It always shows connected but no internet until I run "ipconfig /renew". It wasn't always the case. Last month it worked fine. What could be the reason behind this? Is there a way to fix?

I'm using Windows 10 - 19042.928 build

My phone is using Android 11

Comment: Turn off the device connected to the phone hotspot. Now on the phone, do a soft reset of its network: Put it in Airplane mode, wait one minute, remove from Airplane mode. Restart the phone. Now restart the device and connect it. Any success?